# Selecting a row of pandas series/dataframe by integer index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am curious as to why `df[2]` is not supported, while `df.ix[2]` and `df[2:3]` both work.

```
In [26]: df.ix[2]
Out[26]: 
A    1.027680
B    1.514210
C   -1.466963
D   -0.162339
Name: 2000-01-03 00:00:00

In [27]: df[2:3]
Out[27]: 
                  A        B         C         D
2000-01-03  1.02768  1.51421 -1.466963 -0.162339
```

I would expect `df[2]` to work the same way as `df[2:3]` to be consistent with Python indexing convention. Is there a design reason for not supporting indexing row by single integer?

Comment: `df.ix[2]` does not work - at least not in `pandas version  '0.19.2'`

Answer (score 797, accepted):

echoing @HYRY, see the new docs in 0.11

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Here we have new operators, `.iloc` to explicity support only integer indexing, and `.loc` to explicity support only label indexing

e.g. imagine this scenario

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2),index=range(0,10,2),columns=list('AB'))

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
          A         B
0  1.068932 -0.794307
2 -0.470056  1.192211
4 -0.284561  0.756029
6  1.037563 -0.267820
8 -0.538478 -0.800654

In [5]: df.iloc[[2]]
Out[5]: 
          A         B
4 -0.284561  0.756029

In [6]: df.loc[[2]]
Out[6]: 
          A         B
2 -0.470056  1.192211
```

`[]` slices the rows (by label location) only

Answer (score 118):

#### The primary purpose of the DataFrame indexing operator, `[]` is to select columns.

When the indexing operator is passed a string or integer, it attempts to find a column with that particular name and return it as a Series.

So, in the question above: `df[2]` searches for a column name matching the integer value `2`. This column does not exist and a `KeyError` is raised.

---

#### The DataFrame indexing operator completely changes behavior to select rows when slice notation is used

Strangely, when given a slice, the DataFrame indexing operator selects rows and can do so by integer location or by index label.

```
df[2:3]
```

This will slice beginning from the row with integer location 2 up to 3, exclusive of the last element. So, just a single row. The following selects rows beginning at integer location 6 up to but not including 20 by every third row.

```
df[6:20:3]
```

You can also use slices consisting of string labels if your DataFrame index has strings in it. For more details, see [this solution on .iloc vs .loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation/46915810#46915810).

I almost never use this slice notation with the indexing operator as its not explicit and hardly ever used. When slicing by rows, stick with `.loc/.iloc`.

Answer (score 33):

You can think DataFrame as a dict of Series. `df[key]` try to select the column index by `key` and returns a Series object.

However slicing inside of [] slices the rows, because it's a very common operation.

You can read the document for detail:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics

Comment: The dictionary concept is particularly helpful when iterating over a `groupby` object. Nice to unify the two. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

To index-based access to the pandas table, one can also consider *numpy.as_array* option to convert the table to Numpy array as

```
np_df = df.as_matrix()
```

and then

```
np_df[i]
```

would work.

Comment: that defeats the whole purpose of the dataframes indexes and everything else pandas offers

Answer (score 7):

You can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L1890) .

`DataFrame` has a private function `_slice()` to slice the `DataFrame`, and it allows the parameter `axis` to determine which axis to slice. The `__getitem__()` for `DataFrame` doesn't set the axis while invoking `_slice()`. So the `_slice()` slice it by default axis 0.

You can take a simple experiment, that might help you:

```
print df._slice(slice(0, 2))
print df._slice(slice(0, 2), 0)
print df._slice(slice(0, 2), 1)
```

Answer (score 7):

you can loop through the data frame like this .

```
for ad in range(1,dataframe_c.size):
    print(dataframe_c.values[ad])
```

Answer (score 3):

I would normally go for `.loc/.iloc` as suggested by Ted, but one may also select a row by transposing the DataFrame. To stay in the example above, `df.T[2]` gives you row 2 of `df`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to index multiple rows by their integer indexes, use a list of indexes:

```py
idx = [2,3,1]
df.iloc[idx]
```

N.B. If `idx` is created using some rule, then you can also sort the dataframe by using `.iloc` (or `.loc`) because the output will be ordered by `idx`. So in a sense, `iloc` can act like a sorting function where `idx` is the sorting key.