# How to take random sample of a cvs file in Python?

Tags: python, ipython, sampling

I am new to Python and want to learn Data Wrangling process using it. I am using jupyter for this.

I have a file named fle with 81,000 rows and 89 columns. I want to randomly select about 100 rows from it. How do I do that? I keep on getting following error.

```
fle=pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Mine\Documents\ssample.csv", low_memory=  False)
import random
sampl = random.sample(fle, 10)
```

Error that I am getting is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-fa4ec429f883> in <module>()
      1 import random
      2 #To take a sample of 10000 samples
 ----> 3 sampl = random.sample(fle, 10)
      4 #pd.DataFrame(sampler).head(10)

  C:\Users\E061921\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\random.pyc in sample(self, population, k)
334             for i in xrange(k):         # invariant:  non-selected at [0,n-i)
335                 j = _int(random() * (n-i))
--> 336                 result[i] = pool[j]
337                 pool[j] = pool[n-i-1]   # move non-selected item into vacancy
338         else:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Just use numpy's [random.choice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) on ```np.arange(number_of_rows, replace=False)``` & then index your dataframe by iloc like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096627/pandas-select-row-of-data-frame-by-integer-index).

Answer (score 1):

use `random.choice` instead of sample.  you can use `csv.DictReader` to handle the csv as a list of dicts

```
import csv
import random

random_rows = set()
with open("C:\Users\Mine\Documents\ssample.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

rows = [r for r in reader]
while len(random_rows) < 100:
    random_rows.add(random.choice(rows))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I really appreciate our help.