# pandas - How do I access row in a dataframe by row Index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with 5 rows on which I am doing some validations. If the row does not pass validation, I am adding it to a second dataframe named ValidationFailedDataFrame.

It is OK for the first validation but for the second validation, I want to check if the particular row is already added to the ValidationFailedDataFrame or not and if it is, I want to grab that row and append the error message.

This is how my ValidationFailedDataFrame looks like:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the row that failed the validation was 4th row in the original DataFrame.

How do I query ValidationFailedDataFrame saying give me 4th row of Original DataFrame if you have?

Comment: Is it necessary to make dataframe u can also use dictionary help in finding is the row exist or not

Comment: I would like to keep it dataframe as there are many other things I need to do on the ValidationFailedDataFrame

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas select row of data frame by integer index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096627/pandas-select-row-of-data-frame-by-integer-index)

Comment: `df.iloc[3].tolist()` gives me out-of-bound error as there is only one row in the dataframe. `df.iloc[0].tolist()` works but I would like to access it with `df.iloc[4].tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
ValidationFailedDataFrame.query('index == 4')
```

OR

```
ValidationFailedDataFrame.loc[[4]]
```