# How can I extract the nth row of a pandas data frame as a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Suppose a Pandas dataframe looks like:

```
    BoxRatio  Thrust  Velocity  OnBalRun  vwapGain
5     -0.163  -0.817     0.741     1.702     0.218
8      0.000   0.000     0.732     1.798     0.307
11     0.417  -0.298     2.036     4.107     1.793
13     0.054  -0.574     1.323     2.553     1.185
```

How can I extract the third row (as row3) as a pandas dataframe?
In other words, `row3.shape` should be (1,5) and `row3.head()` should be:

```
 0.417  -0.298     2.036     4.107     1.793
```

Comment: Have you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096627/pandas-select-row-of-data-frame-by-integer-index?

Comment: actually Zero has found detailed appropriate answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas select row of data frame by integer index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096627/pandas-select-row-of-data-frame-by-integer-index)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use `.iloc` with double brackets to extract a DataFrame, or single brackets to pull out a Series.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
>>> df.iloc[[1]]  # DataFrame result
   col1  col2
1     2     4
>>> df.iloc[1]  # Series result
col1    2
col2    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

This [extends to other forms of DataFrame indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) as well, namely `.loc` and `.__getitem__()`:

```
>>> df.loc[:, ['col2']]
   col2
0     3
1     4

>>> df[['col2']]
   col2
0     3
1     4
```

Comment: My favorite thing about pandas is how the solutions to common problems are so discoverable and logical.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can also use [`take`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.take.html):

```
In [4]: df.take([2])
Out[4]: 
    BoxRatio  Thrust  Velocity  OnBalRun  vwapGain
11     0.417  -0.298     2.036     4.107     1.793
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also slice the dataframe. For example, to get the third row as a dataframe, use slice `2:3`.

```py
row3 = df.iloc[2:3]
```