# How to select a specific range of cells in an Excel worksheet with Python library tools

Tags: python, pandas, series

I would like to select a specific range of cells in a workbook worksheet.  I am currently able to set a variable to a workbook worksheet with the line below.

```
 import pandas as pd
 sheet1 = pd.read_excel('workbookname1.xlsx', sheet_name = ['sheet1'])
```

I would like to go one step further and have the ability to select a range of cells in the worksheet so that I can practice dataframe functionality with the defined range.  Some of my ranges are with row values greater than 1000.  How am I able to select a variable length row value for the desired excel range?

Comment: Relevant [selecting-a-row-of-pandas-series-dataframe-by-integer-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096627/selecting-a-row-of-pandas-series-dataframe-by-integer-index/16104482#16104482)

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize `OpenPyXl` module.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("workbookname1.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
cell_range = ws['A1':'C2']
```

You can also use `iter_rows()` or `iter_columns()` methods.

For additional information, you can refer to [OpenPyXL documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/openpyxl/latest/openpyxl.pdf).

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to spend some time looking at OpenPyXl.  This library is new to me.