# How to select certain number of rows in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

So I have a dataframe that is (2624229, 574) and I would like to select only the first 864000 rows, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Read the Pandas documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting a row of pandas series/dataframe by integer index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096627/selecting-a-row-of-pandas-series-dataframe-by-integer-index)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to use *iloc*:

```
n = 864000
df.iloc[:n]
```

The above code **retrieves** initial *n* rows (for now *df* holds all rows).
But if you want to **drop** all rows beyond this limit, run:

```
df = df.iloc[:n]
```

Comment: sorry I explained my question wrong, I wanted to drop all rows after the 864000th row