# Extracting row based on row number

Tags: python

I have a data frame with 100 rows based on user's input I want to extract that particular row.
I have tried using `if row==df.index` but it gives this error *"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"*

Comment: To get a particular row use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).  So to get the i-th row you would have `row = df.iloc[i]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting a row of pandas series/dataframe by integer index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096627/selecting-a-row-of-pandas-series-dataframe-by-integer-index)

Answer (score 0):

If user is inputting the row number i.e. integer location of the row then you can use `df.iloc[I]`.

If user is inputting the index of the row, then you can use `df.loc[I]`

If something else then please update your question with more information